# SOSL Query returns an Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I am trying to display related contacts on the record detail page based on the current Contact record id. For the related contacts, my SOSL as follows:

```
String searchQuery = 'FIND \''  + firstName + ' OR ' + lastName + 
                         '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Name,Email,AccountId WHERE Id != \' '+ contId + '\') LIMIT 10';
    List<List<sObject>> relCons= search.query(searchQuery);
```

I am passing firstName, lastName and contId as parameters to the method.

Error I get on the VF page (on the contact record detail page):

> Content cannot be displayed: invalid ID field: 0033500000XXXXXXXX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have an extra space in your query, right after the opening quote in the where clause.

Turn `!= \' '+ contId + '\')` into `!= \''+ contId + '\')`

Answer (score 2):

You injected a leading space:

```
RETURNING Contact(Name,Email,AccountId WHERE Id != \' '+ contId + '\')
                                                     ^
```

So the invalid filter value looks like: `' 003...'`. Remove this leading space:

```
RETURNING Contact(Name,Email,AccountId WHERE Id != \''+ contId + '\')
```